# Just installed Lumen and got NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2, lumen-routing

I'm searching for a solution ... it's getting so frustrating.
After a fresh installation of Lumen by Laravel, I simply can't access the "/" route. When I try to, it throws an error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 443:

in RoutesRequests.php line 443
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('0')) in RoutesRequests.php line 380
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}() in RoutesRequests.php line 629
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 382
at Application->dispatch(null) in RoutesRequests.php line 327
at Application->run() in index.php line 28
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lumen installation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974469/lumen-installation-error)

Comment: Can't vote again. Found a better duplicate with more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Got it! ....

The solution is to change in public/index.php at line 28:

```
$app->run();
```

to

```
$app->run($app->make('request'));
```

No clue why, maybe you know.

Comment: This fixed a similar issue I was having while attempting to deploy a Laravel 5 application to a production environment. I would also love to know why this works.

Comment: Had the same issue with IIS 8 and lumen and this fixed it

Comment: Worked for me on a local MAMP......i think this is stupid. Why does this  Bug/Feature occur?

Comment: Not work for me only this line written Lumen (5.5.2) (Laravel Components 5.5.*)

Comment: @AnandPandey same with me. did you get the solution

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today.

I was accessing it using the url
http://localhost/lumen.api/public/ and I think that was the cause of the error.

To get around it, this is what I did:

First I configured a new VirtualHost entry on Xampp, located in "C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf" in my case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lumen.api/public"
    ServerName lumen.api
    ServerAlias www.lumen.api
    ErrorLog "logs/lumen.api-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lumen.api-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/lumen.api/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted Apache on Xampp.

Then I edited my hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) to map a new address to my localhost.

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost   
    127.0.0.1       lumen.api
```

I tried again using the new URL http://lumen.api and the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved by changing the

```php
    $app->run();
```

in `/public/index.php` to

```php
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
    $app->run($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the .htaccess file was deleted or somehow missing from `public` folder. Without it the rewrite URL will not work.

Check this: https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/public/.htaccess