# Lumen routing doesn't work

Tags: php, routes, apache2, lumen

Here is my routing code:

```
$app->get('/foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
$app->get('/', function(){
    return 'asd';
});
```

the problem is that I always get "asd" on the page, even if I visit some random route, which doesn't exist. So if I visit localhost/sadgasgasdgsa I will get 'asd' on the page. I also get 'asd', instant of 'Hello World', when I visit localhost/foo. Any ideas what the problem my be?

Note:
This seems like the same question:
[Lumen routes not working other than '/' route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152584/lumen-routes-not-working-other-than-route?rq=1)
However nobody has answered the question. My server confirmation simple WAMP, php 7, apache2 and mysql. While searching for solution, I added the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

However it isn't working
EDIT
For those who came here with the search engine, I've down-graded the version of lumen, and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded from Lumen 5.3 to 5.4 and had the same problem, only '/' route worked.

Digging in revealed that I had broken the code as the solution for earlier problem in Lumen 5.2 that was fixed according to this popular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36436984/1412737).

Problem was in bootstrap/index.php:

`$app->run($app->make('request'))`

Input parameter `$app->make('request')`, which was added as the fix of Laravel 5.2 problem, made an empty request object that was missing actual request data. That's why default '/' kicked in, request object did not have any path info.

I looked the original [public/index.php](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/public/index.php) file in github and `$app->run()` did not have any parameter. When I deleted the `$app->make('request')` input parameter the app started working.