# Lumen: NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 229, Dispatcher NOT_FOUND

Tags: lumen, laravel-passport

I tried a vue-lumen-tutorial with laravel-passport. All works fine for me except the LoginController (login by user and password).
I think its not a problem of the tutorial code, its more a server or laravel/lumen configuration problem. But i am not sure.
The code runs remote on a linux machine (18.04), apache server with Lumen (5.8.12) (Laravel Components 5.8.*) and with Passport.
The api endpoints are available but the /login endpoint gives a 404 Not found.

I found here some questions/answers concerning the index.php of lumen or .htaccess file.  [Just installed Lumen and got NotFoundHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436967/just-installed-lumen-and-got-notfoundhttpexception) . But it doesn't help me.

I am testing with Postman:

```
GET  to https://domain/api/companies/     works fine, 
POST to https://domain/api/oauth/token    works fine, but
POST to https://domain/api/login          gives a 404 Not found.

The route /login is ok.
...
return app()->version(); only for testing gives a request but i need the $tokenRequest:
...
return app()->dispatch($tokenRequest); => 404 Not found
...
error message:
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RoutesRequests.php line 229
...
protected function handleDispatcherResponse($routeInfo)
{
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
case Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
throw new NotFoundHttpException;   <== 229
case Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($routeInfo[1]);
case Dispatcher::FOUND:
return $this->handleFoundRoute($routeInfo);
}
}
...
Maybe a proxy issue between /oauth/token and /login? What can i do?
```

LoginController here in row 45: https://github.com/aibim/vue-lumen-tutorial/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The APP_URL path .env was wrong.  I

```
wrong: APP_URL=https://domain.de/public/
right: APP_URL=https://domain.de/
```